# changing colour of listbox value using droppable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change the colour of listbox value using a droppable div.

```
<div>
<table><tr><td>Selected  First Names</tr><tr><td>
<select name="selectedfirstnames" id="listbox" size="11" multiple="multiple" >

    <option>--selected names--</option>

</select>
 </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

populating listbox values using javascript function below:

```
               function populatelistbox(selectedvalue){

            var select1 = $('#listbox');
            select1.append("<option name='selectedfirstnames' 
               value='"+fnamelist
               [selectedvalue]+"'>"+fnamelist[selectedvalue]+"</option>");

            }
```

Below div are draggable. 
                 Red
                 Green
                 Blue

When i drag and drop these div to list-box , colour of listbox's value should change. 
can anyone please help me to achieve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/manjitwaikhom/3T4bA/

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Edward i have provided the link after you asked